# UITableView addcell to bottom in edit mode

Tags: uitableview, nsarray

I'm trying to make my table add a cell at the bottom of the table for adding cells, my table is on delete mode, so people can delete, but then then i need it to add a cell with insert that will insert a cell. i get errors saying my app isn't consistent with the nsarray. how could i make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 override setEditing on your tableViewController to insert or delete the add row

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate
{
    BOOL prevEditing = self.editing;

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animate];
    [tableView setEditing:editing animated:animate];
    if (editing && !prevEditing) {
        // started editing
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:....] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (!editing && prevEditing) {
        // stopped editing
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:....] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }


}
```

Then ensure you are returning the right number of rows

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger numberOfRows = xxxxxx;

    if (self.editing) {
        numberOfRows++;
    }
    return numberOfRows;
}
```